# Tasks & Exceptions Issue

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am new to tasks and I hope you can help me out with this.

Here is code:

```
Task tast = null;
try
{
   tast = new Task(() =>
   {
     ...
   });
   tast.Start();
   if (tast != null)
   {
      tast.Wait();
      if (tast.Exception != null)
      {
         // catch exception here
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
  // not here? 
}
```

The exception is being caught inside catch statement but not inside task.Exception != null.

Why is this happening? Task should be on own thread.

I would rather like to make the task know about exception and then ask if exception != null.

How can I make that work?

I am sorry in case this is a duplicate. Just let me know in comments and I will remove this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling [`Task.Wait()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.wait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - which will throw an exception if the task is faulted. If you don't call `Task.Wait()`, you won't get the exception in your thread... but of course you won't spot when it's finished, either. There are various ways you *could* wait until it's finished (such as attaching a continuation task and waiting until *that* completes) but the simplest approach is just to call `Task.Wait()` with a catch block:

```
try
{
    task.Wait();
}
catch (AggregateException)
{
    // We'll handle this later.
}
```

Comment: To sum up wait() is checking for exception inside task and throwing them to gui? Is that what you meant?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Well it's waiting for the task to complete in any way, and if the task completed by faulting or being cancelled, `Wait` will throw an exception to the caller, as documented.

Comment: Will Wait() also throw exception even when Task was finished before wait was called?

Comment: @devhedgehog: Only if it was faulted or cancelled. Not if it just completed normally. Note that if this is in the UI thread, you *really* shouldn't be calling `Wait`. You don't want to freeze the UI, do you? If you're using C# 5, look into async/await.

Comment: What would you suggest to following constillation: I have 2 complicated operations both need to access to database. Therefore I thought I would let them run parallel. One inside UI thread and one inside the Task from above. When they both ended I need to match results and do some filtering. So I need to wait for the parallel task in case its not done. What choices do I have?

Comment: Well as I mentioned before, I'd use async/await if you've got access to C# 5, using `Task.WhenAll` to create a single task you can wait for, which will only complete when both of your other tasks complete. Otherwise, you could attach a continuation to each task...

Comment: I am in .net 4 :) could you tell me more about continuation? They wouldnt run parallel would they then? One would follow after another, no?

Comment: @devhedgehog: You can still use async/await in .NET 4. It's the *language* version which is important. And for more information about continuations, you should do some research. You would start *two tasks* (neither of them in the UI thread - why do you want to make your users hate you?) and then have continuations to update the UI when the tasks had completed.

Comment: I am afraid Jon that each task takes up to 10 secounds and allowing users to click around while I am accessing the database would also allow users to click on search over and over again because they see they can interact with UI but nothing is happening. They might think they didnt click search button in first place and therefore they will click on search or exit over and over again. I cant kill accessing to database once started. Users need to see some circle rotating and indicating them that the search has begun and they shouldnt click around or try to change values. :) What do you think?

Comment: @devhedgehog: So disable the search button, and set the cursor to a "busy" one - you don't need to freeze the whole UI just because you're working.

Comment: Still not that easy for me I guess. Buttons in my case are usually disabled once the search textboxes contain invalid input such as invalid characters. Disabling happens when user clicks outside the Textbox including on Button itself. Users might thing the input is wrong and they will start changing the values of the textboxes which I need for the search. Users can come up with craziest things to do and I cant disabled everything possible just to single to the user that he/she shouldn't enter anything. Better would be to freeze the mask instead of disabling everything. Dont you think?

Comment: @devhedgehog: No, I don't. I don't think that freezing the UI so I can't even move the window is *ever* a good idea. But we're now a long way off the topic of your original question.

Comment: I agree with you. I ll try to convice my clients to let the ui unfrozen. Its their decision. Its not my decision. You answered my question. Thanks.